# Aligning span next to div inside tr creates a gap between them

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have aligned a `span` next to `div` as shown below but there is a spacing between the elements. Can someone tell me what is causing it to appear and how to remove it?

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
         <div id="headerDiv" style="">DIV</div>
         <span id="labelSpan">test</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/divm/w3sjrgc4/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `inline-block` will create a space when elements are on a new line. (The most frustrating example is when you want `li` to be side-by-side.

Either do this:

```
<div id="headerDiv" style="">DIV</div><span id="labelSpan">test</span>
```

Or this:

```
<div id="headerDiv" style="">DIV</div><!--
--><span id="labelSpan">test</span>
```

Alternatively, you can do `float:left;` instead.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3sjrgc4/4/)

Answer (score 3):

The `inline-block` always gives gap. If you don't want that, you can do either:

**Remove the Space**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="headerDiv" style="">DIV</div><!--
         --><span id="labelSpan">test</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/w3sjrgc4/2/

Or use `float`:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="headerDiv" style="">DIV</div>
            <span id="labelSpan">test</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

td {
    overflow: hidden;
}

td > span {
    float: left;
    border:2px solid;
}
td > div {
    float: left;
    border:2px solid;
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/vt4kr35w/

Answer (score 2):

This spacing is caused by white spaces (both elements have inline layout), you can get read of them by :

- [pushing elements next to each other in one line](http://jsfiddle.net/w3sjrgc4/3/) in the HTML markup;

*Example:*

```
<td>
     <div id="headerDiv">DIV</div><span id="labelSpan">test</span>
</td>
```

- using [`<!-- -->` tags](http://jsfiddle.net/w3sjrgc4/5/);

*Example:*

```
<td>
     <div id="headerDiv">DIV</div><!--
  --><span id="labelSpan">test</span>
</td>
```

- using [`word-spacing`](http://jsfiddle.net/w3sjrgc4/8/) CSS property.

*CSS:*

```
td {word-spacing: -100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called `white space` and occurs between inline (or inline-block) elements when there's space (on the same line or a new line) in the markup.

Here are **a few solutions** for you:

**Solution 1-** Remove the white space in the markup:

```
<div id="headerDiv" style="">DIV</div><span id="labelSpan">test</span>
```

***Demo***: http://jsfiddle.net/w3sjrgc4/7/

**Solution 2-** Set the `font-size` to 0 on the container then retrieve it on the children.

***Demo***: http://jsfiddle.net/w3sjrgc4/9/

**Solution 3-** Comment out the white space in the markup:

```
<div id="headerDiv" style="">DIV</div><!--
--><span id="labelSpan">test</span>
```

***Demo***: http://jsfiddle.net/w3sjrgc4/10/

**Solution 4-** Left float the children and clear the container to maintain normal document flow on the height.

***Demo***: http://jsfiddle.net/w3sjrgc4/11/